# Static resources are loading from incorrect domain

Tags: lightning-web-components, static-resources

There is an issue with static resources. I have managed package containing static resources with a library. This library is used within LWC component. Recently, we have started facing an issue with this LWC component on several orgs where this package was installed. But not on the all orgs.
After investigation I have noticed on thing - for orgs containing the issue, the static resources stores the library on the vf.force domain, but LWC component runs on lightning.force domain. Orgs that works correctly contain static resources that reside in lightning.force domain and consequently LWC loads this library with the correct domain.
What can be the issue here? Why vf.force domain is used for some orgs? Can it be changed somehow?